# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while attempting to run a sorting algorithm for pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, g++

I am attempting to create a sorting algorithm for three pointer variables based on the strings that are associated with them. However, every time I attempt to run the program, after I get past the first user data entry point, the Segmentation fault (core dump) error is thrown. I have looked on many sites to research this and have not been able to find an answer that works. I believe it is an error with the memory allocation of my pointer variables, but I have no idea how to fix it or where it is. What should I do to alleviate this? Here is some sample code:

```
//new data type
struct Balloon{
string message=""; //give the balloon object a message and a color
string color="";
};

/// main program
int main (void) {

//Instantiate three Balloon objects.
Balloon *front, *middle, *end, *spare;
front, middle, end, spare = new Balloon; //allocate storage for these variables.

//Ask the user what the messages and colors of the balloons are, and set those values to the pointer variables.

//first balloon
cout << "First balloon text: ";
cin >> front->message; //here is when the error is thrown
cout << "Color: ";
cin >> front->color;
```

I am new to Ubuntu and C++, and have only used Java before, so I apologize for any atrocious errors I may have unwittingly made. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: Note: `front, middle, end, spare = new Balloon;` creates only one balloon and assigns it to `spare`.

Comment: @Hannah B , you dont have to edit your post and correct as per the answer .. keep as its , so the original issue is clear.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to apply the fix given in comments or answers.  Doing so takes away the whole context.  If an answer solves your problem, simply upvote and/or accept it and move on.  I rolled back to the previous state.

Comment: BTW, C++ is not Java nor C#, so you don't need to allocate dynamic memory for variables.  Example:  `Balloon front, middle, end, spare;` will allocate local memory for `front, middle, end,` and `spare`.

Answer (score 1):

```
front, middle, end, spare = new Balloon; //allocate storage for these variables.
```

This only allocates a single `Balloon` struct and assigns `spare` as a pointer to it. None of the other pointers are assigned. To allocate all of the balloons, you need to do each one individually:

```
front = new Balloon();
middle = new Balloon();
// etc.
```

If you turn on all of your compiler warnings, you will get a message about this mistake. For example, with `g++`, you can do

```
g++ -Wall <filename>
```